# How to customize OSGi prompt in apache felix gogo shell

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

I have an OSGi system running with Apache Felix Gogo shell (version 1.1.2).

I see the prompt `g!` and everything works fine. I can change the prompt in the console by e.g. `prompt="myPrompt>"`.

How can I have this at start up, configured in my config file (config.ini)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply put a startup script in your working directory ./etc/gosh_profile.
In that script you can define the prompt name like
`prompt="myPrompt>"`.

Comment: Is there any web resource where you can look up things like this? I'm sure there is, but where?